# Finding text in string

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have a requirement to find double quotes in the JSON data which are part of the data itself.

Eg: {"Key": "Value", "Key1", "Val"ue1"}

Now the double quote in Val"ue1 needs to be retrieved and not other double quotes.

Any idea of how to achieve this?

Comment: Your JSON seems not valid to me. If you can, either escape this ugly " or use a single quote instead.

Answer (score 0):

How about `: \"([^(?:\"[,}])]*\"[^(?:\"[,}])]*)\"[,}]`?

This regex looks for text between a colon followed by a space and one double quote and another double quote followed by a comman or closing curly brackets. The text between those has to consist of something*, at least one quote, and something*.

*something means anything (including empty string) that does not contain a quote followed by comma or closing curly bracket, as this would end the value.

Applied to your example (corrected to replace the comma by a colon), it returns `Val"ue1`.

```
String json = "{\"Key\": \"Value\", \"Key1\": \"Val\"ue1\"}";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile(": \"([^(?:\"[,}])]*\"[^(?:\"[,}])]*)\"[,}]").matcher(json);

while (m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A regex for extracting data from double-quotes would be `(?<=")[^"]*(?="))`. The parentheses represent the first capture-group which you can extract with `\1` or `$1`.

However, for parsing JSON (and parsing standards in general) it is recommended to use a library; It will be much more readable, understandable and safe than just a regex which may not cover edge-cases (not saying that there would be some here, but take this as an advice in general)

For instance, if you use Java, `Gson` is a nice library for parsing and generating JSON; if you use JavaScript, just use the built-in `JSON`-object. If you don't use any of These languages I'm sure there are other nice libraries for this as well.

Hope this helps